# Apache Queuing CGI-BIN functions

Tags: apache, cgi-bin, queuing

I am running an Apache Server and I have placed a script to generate a report within the CGI-BIN which I can then start running from link in simple webpage I put together.

The script works no problem. What I have noticed though is that if I attempt to run two or more of the same script through the browser they are queued, i.e. the second will not run until the first is done? I was wondering why this happens and if it is possible to turn it off if necessary,

Thanks

Comment: I know of no inherent limitation on the number of CGI requests that can run in parallel - normally Apache forks and execs a new CGI for each request and it should be able to handle many 10s, or 100s of parallel CGIs. I am happy to be proved wrong though...

Comment: Is there any configuration that limits the amount of processes that are allowed to run at once?

Comment: It depends on your OS. On Linux/Unix-like systems, you would use some variant of the `ulimit` command, or something like `sysctl -a | grep proc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was actually Chrome queueing the requests rather apache.

I tried it on different browsers and it worked fine.